# Min margin from top of the page

Tags: html, css

I have 2 sections both 100% height and 100% width, although the first section has background img. When resizing the browser window, when it hits a certain height div element from the second section starts to overlap on the first section. Is it possible to set a min margin from div to the top of the page?

[image]

[image]

CSS

```css
section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.main section.page1 {
  background: rgb(97,66,52);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/2880px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

.main section.page2 {
  background: #F5F5F5;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.form-parent {
  border: 1px solid #9D9D9D;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  height: 400px;
  width: 500px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div id="home">
    <section class="page1">
    </section>
  </div>
  <section class="page2">
    <div id="order">
      <div class='form-parent'>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

sorry for the messy code.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the code and I found that if you set the section css to be

```
section {
 width: 100%;
 min-height: 100vh;
 }
```

The form-parent div is not overlapping

Comment: thanks, I guess it also works. I already found a solution for it. I have changed my section to position absolute and then created an empty div spacer that filled the whole page + set min-height for both spacer and section.

Answer (score 0):

Use @media queries. You can check if its a window height or width or both issue and use the @media query to change the amount of space at different points.